# Why do my categories redirect?

Tags: categories, redirect, links

When I create a new category I can't open it on my website and instead it redirects to another one called 'Macedonia'

E.g. I made a new category called food but when I open the link http://macedoniandirectory.com.au/category/food/

it just goes to:
http://macedoniandirectory.com.au/category/macedonia/
instead

Comment: Try disabling the plugins on your site to see if one of them is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the slug of your category `food` isn't just set to `macedonia`? That would be the most obvious reason for the redirect.

Or maybe a refresh of your permalinks would do the trick?